# I can't print the values to "arka" at excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim i As Double
Dim x As Double
Dim y As Integer
Dim araba As Integer
Dim n As Integer

Dim bobin As Integer
Dim iplik As Integer
n = Sheets("kaynak").Cells(21, 1)
bobin = ((630 - n) / 2)

    
Dim j As Integer
    For j = 1 To 10
    iplik = Sheets("kaynak").Cells(j, 1)
    For i = bobin To bobin + iplik
        If i <= 315 Then
        
                x = 7 - Int(i / 45) 'kaçıncı satır'
                y = 45 - (i Mod 45)
            Sheets("front").Cells(x, y) = Sheets("kaynak").Cells(j, 2)
        Else
            If i = 630 Then
                x = 7
            Else
                x = Int(i / 45) - 6
            End If
                y = 46 - (i Mod 45)
            Sheets("arka").Cells(x, y) = Sheets("kaynak").Cells(j, 2)
        End If
    Next i
    bobin = bobin + iplik
    Next j
```

my problem is at the title actually i want to print values to "arka" but it does just to "front" it works truely for front but doesn't go for further and i stopts at 315 ,i got error 1004 application defined or object defined error

Comment: What are the values of `i` `j` `x` and `y` when you get the error?

Comment: Are you sure that you have a sheet named `"arka"` and not something like `"arka "` or `" arka"` or something with a Unicode character which happens to look like a latin character? In any event, it is hard to say much without having a [mcve].

Comment: well i am sure about name of the sheet x and y are excel cell coordinates actually and i starts from bobin i use i for loop i got error when i hits the 315 and at the i=316 i want to start print values to "arka"

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: It stops when it must go and start to print  sheet "arka"

Comment: When you are in debug mode, you should be able to find the exact values of `i,j,x,y` -- what are they?

Comment: yeah i will look just a wc break :D also the Sheets("front").Cells(x, y) = Sheets("kaynak").Cells(j, 2) line throws the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `i = 315` (the last pass when `i <= 315`) then

```
x = 7 - Int(i / 45) 'kaçıncı satır'
```

gives `x` the value `0`, since `315/45 = 7` exactly.

This causes the line

```
Sheets("front").Cells(x, y) = Sheets("kaynak").Cells(j, 2)
```

to error-out. You never progress beyond that line in that pass through the loop. Thus your code never even attempts to write to sheet `"arka"`.

Perhaps replacing the line

```
x = 7 - Int(i / 45)
```

with

```
x = Application.Max(1,7 - Int(i / 45))
```

will fix the error.

Comment: how can i pass through the loop for attemp printing values to "arka" i am just a newbie on it

Comment: @spasmex97 I have no way of knowing what you want to happen when `i = 315`. You need to debug the code that writes to sheet "front" before you worry about the other sheet. Maybe you just want `i < 315` rather than `i <= 315`, though I literally have no idea since you haven't given any relevant information.

Comment: when it hits to i= 315 it must print the given values to "front" sheet on cell (1,1) and when it hits to 316 it must print given values to sheet "arka" cell(1,45)

Comment: yes thank you it solved my problem now it prints to sheet "arka" but it doesn't print to "arka" Cell(1,1) i am thinking to solve if you have a suggestion i am open